# QT excel editor

Tags: qt

I am working on a test case editor, which is something like a excel sheet.
Where i need a excel sheet cells to enter data, combobox in excel sheet cells & few buttons, text editor.
Something like shown in these links.

http://www.theirishpenguin.com/assets/images/disc_jockey_list.png
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/images/spreadsheet-demo.png
http://multimedia-and-graphics.softlandmark.com/images/screenshots/QuickTime_MOV_QT_MP4_Converter_229513.gif

Please suggest should i use :--
`QT spreadsheet` or `QT treewidget` or `QT modelview` ?

What will be the right class to use, to get maximum flexibility with my editor ?

Answer (score 2):

Base your editor on [QTableWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html) - as the name suggests, it shows a table/grid, and looks very closely like Excel.

There is already an example [spreadsheet application](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/demos-spreadsheet.html) that comes from the Qt team.

Comment: For bigger projects I'd rather suggest to separate Model and View: use `QTableView` and `QAbstractItemModel`

Comment: is it possible to add combobox ---- inside cell of a QAbstractItemModel ?

Comment: The spreadsheet application link is broken. This is the updated link - http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-spreadsheet-example.html